# Excess pressure inside a drop

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, liquid-state

During the derivation of excess pressure inside the liquid drop, if the setup is in equilibrium, we say that the 
force due to surface tension +force due to pressure outside =force due to pressure inside.$$2\pi rT+P_1\pi r^2=P_2\pi r^2$$
T being the surface tension,
My question is why is the force due to surface tension not $2*(2\pi r)T$, even though the liquid hemisphere has 2 surfaces,outside and inside(just like in the case of soap dipped U frame with sliding wire on its arm?).

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Concept of surface tension: excess pressure inside an air bubble in a tank of water](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q399755/)

Comment: @Firefox1921 The possible duplicate is asking why is surface tension present. I am asking why is not twice as in case of soap dipped u frame,both not having air inside them,and having two surfaces up and down.

Comment: there is only 1 surface over the drop ,  while in the case of soap dipped U frame with sliding wire on its arm, there are 2 surfaces

Answer (score 4):

You can say that the total pressure due to surface tension is twice in a soap bubble because it is a bilayer surface, meaning there are really two air-water interface as shown in the picture

[image]

However when the discussion is about a simple water-air interface, you can not say that there is a bilayer simply because it is just one air-water boundary. For each interface, the force is
$T\cdot(2\pi r)$
And thus for something like a droplet or a glass of water, it's just $T\cdot(2\pi r)$ once.

Comment: So if instead of soap in the u frame example, it was water,then the force due to surface tension would be Sl only? where l is the length and S the surface tension?

Comment: @RichardKiddman what  ? no , in  the case of U frame force is $2Sl$, because there are 2 surfaces one in front and other at back.

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't see it was the U frame that was asked. I apologise for the inaccuracy. It is immaterial if it is soap, or water or kerosene. Just count the number of times the liquid and air are face to face and the total force is that many times Sl

Answer (score -1):

Its because a liquid drop has just a single surface, its inside is filled with water whereas a soap bubble has an air-soap interface(in other words surface) on the outside and another one in the inside. You can visualize this with Richard's diagram it helped me too.